# MR action with Customized Command Line Arguments

Tags: mapreduce, oozie

I created an MR job to ingest the data into the Elastic Search Nodes. Below is the command line argument I used to run this MR job for data ingestion.

```
hadoop jar inputdirs outputdir esnode1,esnode2,esnode3,esnode4.
```

Now, through command line arguments I am able to successfully execute it.

Same thing, if I try to do scheduling, I am facing challenges. Oozie MR action accepts only two arguments: `inputdir outputdir`. I am not sure where to provide 3rd argument (i.e `esNodes`) in Oozie workflow in order to execute the MR action as I designed.

Is it possible? If not, do I have to write a regular Java action in Oozie?

Answer (score 0):

You can define argument related to your MR job in workflow.xml file.More information related to workflow.xml can be found [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/Map+Reduce+Cookbook)